# Can't match a-z characters in antlr4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have the following grammar:

```
grammar lab02;

@header{
  package laboratorios.lab02;
}

word    : [a-z]+ ;
op_plus : '+' ;
op_min  : '-' ;
op_mul  : '*' ;
op_div  : '/' ;
WS      : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
digit   : ('0'|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9') ;
```

This gives an error saying: `error(50): lab02.g4:7:10: syntax error: 'a-z' came as a complete surprise to me while matching alternative.`

I have copied it from an example, but it doesn't work on my computer. Take a look at the digit rule: `digit   : ('0'|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9') ;` it is like this because that's the only way it would not report an error. If I use [0-9]+ I get:

```
error(50): lab02.g4:7:10: syntax error: '0-9' came as a complete surprise to me while matching alternative
```

Do you know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ANTLR a rule starting with a lowercase letter is a parser rule, whereas a rule starting with an uppercase letter is a lexer rule.

You are trying to define lexer rules here, so you have to start them with an uppercase letter.

```
WORD    : [a-z]+ ;
OP_plus : '+' ;
OP_min  : '-' ;
OP_mul  : '*' ;
OP_div  : '/' ;
WS      : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
DIGIT   : [0-9] ;
```

Your rule `digit: ('0'|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9');` is actually valid for a parser rule, and that's why it compiles, but it will implicitly create one token type per digit, which is not good.

Comment: It doesn't give any error this way, but it says that my grammar has no rules. I am assuming this is referring to parser rules. Correct?

Comment: Correct. Now you have only lexer rules, so your grammar will produce a valid lexer, but no parser. Add some parser rules and it will produce a parser too.